# TemplateURL not working - request is not sent

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The template does not even appear to be being requested. I tried an absolute URL, a relative URL, and even the full-length URL.

The template is not being requested at all, I've checked.

Here is the code:

```
app.directive('field', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateURL: "http://192.9.200.62:8080/templates/field.html",
        scope : {
            field: "=name",
            ops: "=options"
        }
    };
});
```

Other URLs I've tried include `templates/field.html` and `/templates/field.html` and `../../templates/field.html`.

The template works fine if I build it as a string in JS.

Comment: whats your folder structure?, when you say request not sent, you mean when using the full url or always? and how do you check that the request is not baing sent?

Comment: the template is in `/templates/` , this script is in `/scripts/js/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things here.  First, the template path is always relative to the root.  So, if your `templates` directory is off the root, then this should work:

```
/templates/field.html
```

Second, the property is named `templateUrl`, the case matters here.  So, you need to rename `templateURL` to `templateUrl`.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive) showing the `templateUrl` property.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe it was just the case on the property... URL seems more technicallly correct to me but whatever it's not my library lol.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be templateUrl, not templateURL.

As far as the correct URL to use, what is the folder structure?

Comment: You were correct and answered first but the other answer will be better for other users who see this.